# how to separate a number into numbers with spaces in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

there's a question that asks to find the number of 1s in a binary string
Example if the input string is '10100011' the output is 4.
I wanted first to split the numbers in the string like this '1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1' then convert the string to double and get the sum
But I couldn't find a way to split the number in the string

Comment: Do you have a char array (single quotes, what used to be a called string in the old days) or a string array (double quotes)?

Comment: I am new to MATLAB, so I don't understand the difference but in the question it is binary string with a single quote,

Comment: Ok. See what happens if you compare the string to `'1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of `'1'` characters in `'10100011'` you can do

```
s = '10100011';

n = sum(s=='1');
% or equivalently
n = nnz(s=='1');
```

to answer your question directly, you could create an array of each digit in a char using

```
s = arrayfun(@str2double,s)
% s = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

But in the case of a string purely composed of the characters `'0'` or `'1'` this is equivalent to checking if each character is `=='1'`, albeit slower and less preferable to the comparison shown first.